# Unable to resample the pandas with date column. TypeError Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, resampling, pandas-resample

The dataframe is

```
Date                       Amount
2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30  2055359.98
2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30  2055359.98
2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30  145198200.0
2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30  145198200.0
2019-07-02T00:00:00+05:30  1924232.72
2019-07-02T00:00:00+05:30  137860984.9 
2019-07-02T00:00:00+05:30  137466690.88
2019-07-02T00:00:00+05:30  138102066.04
```

Unable to resample the the below dataframe with dates on sum. I've tried below code to resample into two dates

```
d = df.resample('D', on='Date').sum()
```

The error is

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

I tried converting date column to index and converted to datetime before converting it into index. But the error is :

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-07-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-02', '2019-07-02', '2019-07-02', '2019-07-02', '2019-07-02', '2019-07-02', '2019-07-02', '2019-07-02', '2019-07-02', '2019-07-02', '2019-07-09', '2019-07-09', '2019-07-12', '2019-07-12', '2019-08-19', '2019-08-19', '2019-09-10', '2019-09-10', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-13', '2019-09-13', '2019-09-13', '2019-11-21', '2019-11-22', '2019-11-25', '2019-11-25', '2019-11-25'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='TRANSACTIONDATE', freq=None)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: seems like **you do need datetime functionality**. Parse 'Date' column to datetime before resampling - pd.to_datetime is your friend.

Comment: I've updated the question, please check.

Comment: if I make a df from your example, and run `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`, then `d = df.resample('D', on='Date').sum()` works just fine.

Comment: What about index? Is it not mandatory to convert date to index? And did you change date values?

Comment: Setting a datetime index is optional I think.

Comment: I think it's mandatory. Please check the error i've posted recently. a.ll() and a.any() error

Comment: But when we are resampling by dates, it must sum the values respective to their dates right?

Comment: thats what you get ***after*** resampling, so you don't want to strip time & UTC offset as your other question suggests.

Comment: So, i don't need to remove UTC time? That's what you're saying right?